# Angular JS - {{ }} not working but data-ng-bind display the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I've an issue with Angular JS. I don't get why my data in the scope can't be displayed with the {{ }} but can be display if I use the directive : data-ng-bind.

If anyone has an idea :

Here's my HTML Code :

```
<aside  id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar-left" data-ng-controller="PortalController" data-ng-init="getAppslist()">

    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="sidebar-title">
            Navigation
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-collapsed" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nano" >
        <div class="nano-content">
            <nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav nav-main">
                    <li class="nav-active">
                        <a href="#!/">
                            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!/users">
                            <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span>Users</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-parent">

                        <a href="#!/apps">
                            <i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span>Apps</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-children">
                            <li ng-repeat="app in appslist">
                                <a ng-href="#!/apps/{{app.CloudAppInstanceId}}">{{app.Name}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Here's my controller :

```
angular.module('core').controller('PortalController', ['$scope', 'Portal',
function($scope, Portal) {
    $scope.getAppslist = function() {
        Portal.getApps(function(callback) {
            $scope.appslist = callback;
            $scope.blabla = 'blabla';
        });
    };
}]);
```

And here's my service :

```
angular.module('core').factory('Portal', function($http, $cookies, $rootScope) {
// define factory object
var factory = {};



var getApps = function(callback){
    $http.get($rootScope.logrrApiAddress + '/apps', config).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        callback(data);
    });
}

factory.getApps = function(callback){
    return getApps(callback);
}});
```

Thanks in advance for your response

Martin Taz

Comment: Don't use handlebars in an `ng` prefixed attribute.  Either assemble the `href` in your controller and use `ng-href`, or simply list it as an `href` and use the handlebars.  The first option is preferable.

Comment: Also, your `href` attribute is prefixing the routes when that routing _should_ be handled by your router instead, using something like `$location.path('app/app_instance_id')`.

Comment: which data isn't being displayed here? the items iterated in the `ng-repeat`?  you haven't shown where you are using `ng-bind` in this example.

Comment: @JoshBurgess what is wrong with using handlebars in  `ng-href` ? By your general terms you should pass handlebars to `src` also for an image which is foolish and can cause bad server requests

Comment: @charlietfl – Yeah, that's why I said the first was preferable.  You don't pass in handlebars to an ng-href because it's not going to be interpreted correctly.  If it's dynamic, have it built on the controller/service/whatever.  Use angular in context, don't treat it only as a templating service (as is being done here) since you're bound to break it doing that.  The second option still works (mostly), but it's prone to the kind of breaking you just described.

Comment: @JoshBurgess so why is it documented using handlebars? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref Opinions aside it's hard to argue with the docs and tell someone not to follow them

Answer (score 1):

You don't need handlebars in an ng-href. Try:

```
<a ng href="'#!/apps/' + app.CloudAppInstanceId">{{app.Name}}</a>
```

Better yet would be to turn that into a method on your controller.

Comment: Thanks for you response, you're right about the handlebars in ng-href it's not needed... still I can't have the data display for {{app.Name}}

Comment: @MartinTaz are you saying `ng-bind="app.Name"` works but `{{app.Name}}` doesn't? A demo that replicates this would help

Comment: Actually that's not true (which is pretty confusing). The ng-href directive is only to prevent the user from clicking on a bad link. It doesn't automatically parse anything inside. Check out the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng href="'#!/apps/' + app.CloudAppInstanceId">{{app.Name}}</a>
```

Seems to me that app is not defined in the scope, what you do set in `PortalController`, though, is  `$scope.appslist`.

Also, the `Portal` factory function must return an object instance (it currently doesn't return anything). AND the factory's method must actually return a promise, too.

```
angular.module('core').factory('Portal', [
    '$http', '$cookies', '$rootScope',
    function($http, $cookies, $rootScope) {

        var factory = {};  // define factory object

        factory.getApps = function(){
            // FIXME: what is "config", where is it supposed to come from?
            return $http.get($rootScope.logrrApiAddress + '/apps', config);
        };

        return factory;  // <-- you need to return something
    }
]);

angular.module('core').controller('PortalController', [
    '$scope', 'Portal',
    function($scope, Portal) {
         $scope.getAppslist = function() {
             Portal.getApps().then(function (data) {
                 $scope.apps = data;
                 $scope.blabla = 'blabla';
             });
         };
    }
]);
```

I changed things a bit, esp. got rid of the `callback` parameter - you don't need that, simply get the promise that getApps() returns and use the data once the promise is resolved.